# captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, bevy

I have this code. children are from Bevy query.

```
let array_of_elements = children.into_iter()
                        .filter_map(|&item| {
                            match element_children.get_mut(item) {
                                Ok(value) => Some(value),
                                Err(_) => None,
                            }
                        })
                        .collect();
```

What I need is to get all children to some vector/array type, that can be sent to another function.

Here's the children definition:

```
fn object_interactions(
  ...,
  mut element_children: Query<
    (Option<&mut Text>, Option<&mut Button>, Option<&Interaction>, Entity)
>,
  mut dialog_query: Query<(&mut Style, &mut Children), With<Dialog>>,
...) {
  for (mut style, children) in dialog_query.iter_mut() {

     // here's are all things running inluding this array_of_elements creation

  }

}
```

On Some(value) I get this error:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
   --> src/main.rs:188:46
    |
143 |     mut element_children: Query<
    |     -------------------- variable defined here
...
186 |                         .filter_map(|&item| {
    |                                           - inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
187 |                             match element_children.get_mut(item) {
    |                                   ---------------- variable captured here
188 |                                 Ok(value) => Some(value),
    |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
    |
    = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
    = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

Comment: Please add definitons for the missing items (`children`, `element_children`, ...) so your question includes a [mre], not just some code snippets.

Comment: @cafce25, ok I added information about this.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that is code that we can run by ourselves (and **minimal**).

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution for this, Children's trait is not even needed there, but it's a different problem-specific answer. In brief, I'm just spawning children Entities inside this function instead of creating them before this.